# IConfiguration DI chicken-and-egg question

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, inversion-of-control, .net-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC app written in C#. I want to build a custom `IConfiguration` to add to the providers already registered.

I would like to use some services registered in the DI service collection to implement some of the configuration provider. These services would typically take values from an `IConfiguration` provider.

I want to bootstrap the new `IConfiguration` using services that are configured using information from existing `IConfiguration` providers, and then I want to use the new `IConfiguration` provider to configure more services that I want to add to the services collection.

I might want to add a repository-based `IConfiguration` that needs a connection string to the repository, for example, and I might want to keep setting for other services in the repository.  The repository needs some access service, like EF. but with other service dependencies.  Without DI I might write:

```
int attempts = Confguration["attempts"];
string connectitonString = Configuration["repository"]
IRetry retry = new Retry(attempts);
IConnect connect = new Connect(connectionString, retry);
IRead read = new Read();
IStore store = new Store(connect, read); // has secret
IConfiguration moreConfiguration = new MoreConfiguration(store);
builder.Confguration.Add(moreConfiguration);
string secret = Configuration["secret"];
IService finally = new Service(secret);
finally.DoSomething(...);
```

Naively I could try to instantiate a "temporary" service provider, build the Configuration provider using services from the temporary, add it to the registered configs, then add more services. That doesn't seem a good idea to me, especially if I have singletons and scoped services.

```
int attempts = Confguration["attempts"];
string connectitonString = Configuration["repository"]
builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<IRetry>(_ => new Retry(attempts))
    .AddSingleton<IConnect>(p =>
        {
               IRetry r = p.GetRequiredService<IRetry>();
               return new Connect(connectionString, retry);
        })
    .AddSingleton<IRead, Read>();
    .AddSingleton<IStore>()(p =>
        {
            IConnect c = p.GetRequiredService<IConnect>();
            IRead r = p.GetRequiredService<IRead>();
            return new Store(c, r);
        });
ServiceProvider intermediate = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
IStore store = intermediate.GetRequiredService<IStore>();
IConfiguration moreConfiguration = new MoreConfiguration(store);
builder.Confguration.Add(moreConfiguration);
string secret = Configuration["secret"];
builder.Services.AddTransient<IService>(_ => new Service(secret));
ServiceProvider final = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
IService finally = final.GetRequiredService<IService>();
finally.DoSomething(...);
```

Is there a way to really to use a service provider, then add more services, then use it again? Or am I crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `IServiceProvider` without creating a temp instance, because actions added using `ConfigureAppConfiguration` are executed before the root service provider is created. But you can access information "added on Configuration by previous calls" to  `ConfigureAppConfiguration` just by building the `IConfigurationRoot` from configurationBuilder.

see the example below (also follow [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider) - example is taken from there):

```
using CustomProvider.Example.Providers;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static class ConfigurationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddEntityConfiguration(
        this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        var tempConfig = builder.Build();
        var connectionString =
            tempConfig.GetConnectionString("WidgetConnectionString");

        return builder.Add(new EntityConfigurationSource(connectionString));
    }
}
```

#### Edit

Since more information was provided in the question I will try to give you a concrete example of how you can achieve what you want without creating a temporary ServiceProvider... (example given has compilation error therefore I have modified it to work).

First, you will need to create a `ConfigurationProvider`

```
public class MoreConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    private readonly int _attempts;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MoreConfigurationProvider(int attempts, string connectionString)
    {
        _attempts = attempts;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    
    public override void Load()
    {
        IRetry retry = new Retry(_attempts);
        IConnect connect = new Connect(_connectionString, retry);
        IRead read = new Read();
        IStore store = new Store(connect, read);
        
        // Simple version as per example
        Data.Add("secret", store.GetSecret());
    }
}
```

Then create a `IConfigurationSource`

```
public class MoreConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    public int Attempts { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
    {
        return new MoreConfigurationProvider(Attempts, ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Change your `Service` class to accept `IConfiguration` (this is optional)

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        string sercert = configuration["secret"];
    }
}
```

Finally, change your program.cs

```
int attempts = int.Parse(builder.Configuration["attempts"]);
string connectionString = builder.Configuration["repository"];

builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<IRetry>(_ => new Retry(attempts))
    .AddSingleton<IConnect>(p =>
    {
        IRetry r = p.GetRequiredService<IRetry>();
        return new Connect(connectionString, r);
    })
    .AddSingleton<IRead, Read>()
    .AddSingleton<IStore>(p => 
    {
        IConnect c = p.GetRequiredService<IConnect>();
        IRead r = p.GetRequiredService<IRead>();
        return new Store(c, r); 
    });

builder.Configuration.Add<MoreConfigurationSource>(mc =>
{
    mc.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    mc.Attempts = attempts;
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IService>();
```

Comment: I added some pseudo-code and complicated the use case a bit to better describe my quandary.  I want to register some services, then use those services in my configuration, then build more services using the new configuration.

Comment: Updated the question based on the pseudo-code example you gave :)

Comment: The MoreConfiguration class is now tightly coupled to Retry, Read, Connect, and Store.  I think this is where I am wondering.  Is there a way to have a c'tor injection of those services?
    MoreConfiguration(IRetry r, IConnect c, IRead e, IStore s) {...}

Comment: Since configuration providers are added before Host is built, you will have to use it as I described or stick with your approach creating sp manually.

Comment: I see, thank you.  This suggests that .NET configuration providers need to be designed without the benefit .NET DI.